# Is there a way to reformat CSV using Save As in C# to fix a corrupt CSV that has string and commas characters in formatting?

Tags: c#, csv, type-conversion

I have a CSV file where the file has string characters and one extra comma. When I open the file, Excel opens it just fine, but when I open the file as a text file, I can see that the formatting has string characters and an extra comma at the very end of the record. I can open the file and use Save As to reformat the file and then it is in a correct CSV format, but I would like to use SSIS C# script to fix the file automatically without using interop. Is there a way to do this?

Example (Correct Format):

**FirstName, LastName, FullName**

Format that I am getting (Incorrect Format):

**"FirstName", "LastName", "FullName",**

Comment: But how are the CSV files being written? This needs some code snips

Comment: What is an "SSIS C# script"?  Can you use 3rd party nugets like [tag:CsvHelper]?  Incidentally your second CSV sample doesn't look 'corrupt", instead it looks to be escaped using [rfc 4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180#section-2) escaping.  So CSV readers that support this can read the second format automatically.

Comment: What you really have (regardless of whether the producing party intended it)  is a CSV file that has 4 fields, not 3, and the last one is always empty. Try loading it as such.

Comment: Or, you could wrap the text reader in another text reader that removes the comma when reading the line.

Comment: I don't know how they are being written, but this is the format that I get every time that I download them from a web API.